# How can I make ER diagrams?

Tags: erd

I need to make ER diagrams for a given set of Excel documents, but just don't see the links between the tables. Here the Excel sheets:

[Excel sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwVdD.png)

[Excel sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07913.png)

And here the ERD I came up with: [image]

I tried looking at other examples, but I understand them when it's solved, but don't seem to be able to solve it myself. How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

### Very basic approach

The very basic approach is to look at each file, list the columns, and find out if any column uniquely identifies the lines in the table:

- Table 1: The first column (ending with id) seems to be the identifier of the courses.  The remaining columns describe attributes of the course, such as language, timing, day of the week, number of students, etc.
- Table 2: The first column looks like an identifier for a room,  and the second column is the name of the campus of that room.

As a first measure, you can represent each of these table as a distinct entity in your model, with its attributes, and identify the primary key (PK).

You then need to find out columns in one table that look like columns in the other table.  In particular, you'll look for the identifier columns of one table to see if it is used in another table.  Sometimes they have the same name.  Sometimes they have similar names and there is obviously the same values as content.  Obviously, you'd better check if the hypothesis works:

- Candidate 1:  Table 1, column `Klaslokaal` seems to refer to table 2, identifying column `LokaalId`.  Of course, the name is not a guarantee,  but cross-checking it appears that every value of `Klaslokaal` exist in `LokaalId`.  We can also see that some values in `LokaalId` are repeated several times in `Klaslookal`.

This will allow you to draw the relationships between tables.  You then need to find out about the cardinality (i.e. primary key in Table1 is unique,  so it'll be a one-to-xxx relationship.  On the other side, we see that the same value can be repeated, so you can fine-tune the relationship as one-to-many.  If some column may have some cells that remain empty,  it's an optional relationship.

### More advanced processing

The more advance processing is related to database normalisation techniques.  I will not be able to summarise here a set of techniques that are usually described in specialized books over several chapters.  But here the most relevant ones:

- You'll see in Table 1, that all the courses within a same room always have the same number of places.  This is called a functional dependency.  it tells us that probably the number of places is not an attribute of the course,  but an attribute of the room in which a course takes place.  You'll move that attribute to the right entity.
- In the same way,  you'll see that for each repetition of the course name,  the course description, the responsible, and the language are the same.  This is another functional dependency.  In this case, you'd create an additional entity `Cursus` and move the related attributes therein. As there is no id,  you'd add an id column in the new entity,  and replace all the moved attributes in the original tables with a reference to this id.  This is missing in your diagram.

Note that there is no need to have a course/room entity:  the fact that one course is related to several "Lesrooster", and that several Lesrooster can be related to the same room, allow to deduce this information.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This explained it very clearly.